# Printer options only offer portrait, no option to switch

Tags: cocoa, printing, nsprintoperation, nsprintinfo

I'm using `[[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:drawingView] runOperation];` and I get this view:

[image: printer preview window]

There is no option to choose between Landscape or Portrait
I found that I can have `[[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:drawingView printInfo:info] runOperation];`
and set `info.orientation = NSPaperOrientationLandscape` . In that case I would get the preview in landscape but the user does not have the option.

How can I offer the option? (note: I don't see it under 'show Details' either)

Comment: What does Show Details show?

Comment: @DDP a complicated view but nothing about Landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portrait and landscape buttons are in the page layout panel (Page Setup… in the File menu). See `NSPageLayout` and `-[NSApplication runPageLayout:]`. It is possible to add the portrait and landscape buttons to the print panel:

```
NSPrintPanel *printPanel = printOperation.printPanel;
printPanel.options |= NSPrintPanelShowsOrientation;
```

and/or

```
printPanel.options |= NSPrintPanelShowsPageSetupAccessory;
```